# How to import IIS certificate into Chrome to avoid untrusted site warning?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, web, ssl-certificate, local

When developing and testing SSL enabled sites locally (Windows 8 + local IIS), I use Chrome as main browser for testing/preview, and to avoid 'untrusted certificate' warning window in Chrome when opening local site, I used to append "--ignore-certifcate-errors" flag to Chrome launch shortcut.
However recently that flag was depreciated and show yet another warning "you are using an unsupported command-line flag: --ignore-certificate-errors.".
I wanted to avoid this warning as well, so how do I do it now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I found later, disabling "--ignore-certificate-errors" was intentional (see here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=376424), and the better option to avoid warnings was to import you local SSL into Chrome directly.

Here is how you do it from under IIS in Windows:

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Select your site
3. Click 'Bindings' > select 'https' one > click 'Edit' to see which certificate is used for the site (IIS Express Development Certificate was default for me)
4. Select server root on the left > click 'Server Certificates'
5. Find your site's certificate > right click on it > select 'Export...'
6. Click '...' to select location to save file, make sure you give the file same name as your Certificate name (e.g. in my case it's 'IIS Express Development Certificate.pfx') and set any password (e.g. 1234) > Click 'OK' to export
7. Now that your certificate is saved, got to Chrome settings > search for 'Manage certificates' (or open this in Chrome **chrome://settings/search#Manage%20certificates**) > click 'Manage certificates...' button
8. Click 'Import...' button below and Import wizard will show up, click 'Next'
9. Browse for your file, make sure extension in Open file dialog is set to 'All FIles', click 'Next'
10. On next screen enter your password as you set before (e.g. 1234 in this case), click 'Next', select 'Automatically select the certificate store ...', and 'Next' again, and 'Finish' finally.
11. Your're done! Now restart Chrome and your local website should show green lock icon next to 'https' in address bar

Comment: In case you want a quicker way, you can use Jexus Manager, https://blog.lextudio.com/why-chrome-says-iis-express-https-is-not-secure-and-how-to-resolve-that-d906a183f0 (The steps for IIS Express also apply to full IIS).